# Mount CIFS/SMB share to Android 10 as folder?

Tags: mount, cifs

Im trying to mount cifs share to android 10 rooted phone and i already mount it but i cant see files in folder in other apps only in rooted one. It is possible to do something like that to get  access from all apps to cifs share?

Comment: Mount in global namespace. See [How to mount NFS on Android with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201191/218526) and [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526) and [Why partition gets unmounted automatically after some time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200449/218526)