# Accessing NFS share

Tags: applications

I'm trying to develop a very basic NFS Android client. I don't need to actually mount the NFS share, just list, read, and write files.

I can't seem to find any NFS-related APIs in the Android API reference, nor any Android-compatible Java-based NFS libraries.

What's the easiest way to access NFS shares programmatically in Android?

Comment: NFS is complex, won't work without kernel support: [How to mount NFS on Android with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201191/218526)

Comment: That doesn't pass the basic smell test as my Kodi application on my Nvidia Shield reads media files on the local network over NFS