# CIFS mount SMB into a folder results in "no such device" error on Android 10 Lineageos 17.1 and stock Google Pixel

Tags: mount, cifs

I've tried these commands with root access

```
mount -t fifs //192.168.62.118/xyz -o username=user,password=pw /mnt/sdcard/xyz

mount -t cifs //192.168.62.118/xyz -o username=user,password=pw /mnt/sdcard/xyz

mount iocharset=utf8 -t cifs -o username=user,password=pw,rw,noperm,iocharset=utf8 //192.168.62.118/xyz /mnt/sdcard/xyz 

mount -o username=user,password=pw,nodfs,rw,iocharset=utf8,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 -t cifs //192.168.62.118/xyz /storage/self/primary/xyz
```

all of them results in "no such device". Googling around, it seems its due to the kernel not supporting CIFS. But this also happen in LineageOS 17.1 where other people reports able to mount cifs, albeit on a different device.

WHat I could do to get cifs smb mount working?

Comment: If [mount](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) returns `ENODEV` (no such device) error it always indicates: *"filesystemtype not configured in the kernel"*. You can simply check if your kernel supports CIFS: `grep cifs /proc/filesystems`. Might be helpful: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201191/218526