# Photo transfer from Android device (no screen) to Android smartphone

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, camera, wifi-hotspot, file-transfer

I am working on an Android passtime project. I have a camera device that runs on Android 8.1. This camera device doesn't have a Screen. I am trying to identify the best way to transfer photos from the camera device to my smartphone. So, I see a few options.

1. Pair the camera device with my smartphone over Bluetooth. This way, I can transfer photos over Bluetooth. In this approach, I will be building a background Android service and pushing it to the camera which can take care of transferring the photos.
2. Have a hotspot turned on on my smartphone. Connect the camera device with the smartphone's hotspot. This way, I can upload the photos captured to Firebase or some other cloud platform and later pull the photos on the smartphone
3. Make the camera device utilize the data connection of my smartphone. I am not sure if this is feasible.

I am evaluating these options to identify which will be a better option. I am trying to understand what kind of Android services I would have to build and push to the camera device and my smartphone. Any thoughts/insights are welcome.

Details about the camera device:

1. The camera device (camera module) has both Bluetooth and wifi capabilities.
2. The camera device is not stationary. So it can't be connected with home wifi or specific wifi. But the camera will always remain closer to my smartphone.
3. As the camera runs on Android, I can build services/APKs and push them to the camera. The same applies to my smartphone.

I am trying to find more details on how the photo transfer works on devices like Google glass.

Comment: Regarding 1.: If the camera has no screen how would you start a transfer over Bluetooth? Bluetooth is AFAIR push only not pull, so you would have to start the copy operation on the camera. Usually cameras without screen provide an app that does the image transfer, what camera are you talking about?

Comment: @Robert I can build a background service and push it to my camera device. This is a custom camera I am building from a Camera module.

Comment: Just a note that while the overall question might be on-topic for this community, app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues.

Comment: does camera have storage? you could just adb pull over tcpip (wifi or bluetooth)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make mounted cifs/smb share visible for normal user in Android-x86](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245392/make-mounted-cifs-smb-share-visible-for-normal-user-in-android-x86)

Comment: Yes. the camera has storage.

Comment: Isn't adb over bluetooth a hacky approach? i.e. Would devices live Meta Smart Glasses and other devices used adb over bluetooth?

Comment: I don't think adb is used for anything other except debugging because it provides no security

Comment: @alecxs That's exactly my point. So I am trying to see what is the better option to transfer photos.

Comment: kindly self-answer your question with final solution, so we can use for further reference