# How to mount AFP/SMB drive to Nox Player?

Tags: mount, macos, cifs, noxplayer

I use the latest version of Nox Player (android emulator) on Mac OS Catalina.

I would like to mount my AFP or SMB drive to Nox Player.

I've connected to Nox Player thru ADB:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
```

Now I am trying to mount the drive:

```
 mount -t afp afp://login:pass@192.168.1.5/photo /sdcard/DCIM
```

(`/sdcard/DCIM` folder exists)

But it returns the error `No such device`. I tried to `su` before executing the command. I tried to mount to another folder (`/mnt/sdcard/xyz`, `/storage/self/primary/DCIM`), but it doesn't help.

The command given above works well if executed directly on my Mac. I've tried to `ping 192.168.1.5` from Nox player and it works well. I've tried to open the same storage within Nox Player built-in Amaze file browser as SMB share and it also works.

I've read [How to mount NFS on Android with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200867/how-to-mount-nfs-on-android-with-correct-permissions/201191#201191), but it is not quite clear for me what else could be tried.

What should I try?

Comment: I don't think that Android contains the necessary drivers for AFP or SMB protocol as these are not needed by regular Android devices.

Comment: @Robert, looks like the missing drivers/modules could be added manually, but the question is where to take them for Nox Player or how to compile it. 

What is about other protocols? Can I try to use NFS or something else?